# Using socket.io from a module

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My `sio = require('socket.io').listen(app)` is in my server.js file, but I'm calling a method in a library that would like to push a message to the client... say `api.user.pushToClient()`

How am I able to access `sio.sockets` from there? Perhaps my structure is incorrect?

**Folder structure:**

`server.js`

`api`

`|--user.js`

`|--another.js`

Comment: Should you declare sio as a variable? How does JavaScript handle sio without the var keyword?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in `server.js` append this line

```
module.exports.sio = sio;
```

in `api/user.js`

```
sio = require('../server').sio;
sio.sockets.on ...
```

Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: That might be what I was looking for, I'll try that out when I get a chance. Thanks.

Comment: So when I use the sio. is it passed by reference from server.js?

Answer (score -1):

What I understood from the question is you want to know how to use socketIO with node module.Based on my understanding you can use it as below:
First install socketIO module locally with npm by running " $npm install socket.io " command for windows.

Add Script to your HTML page:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Now add var io = require('socket.io'); to your server or js file where you are going to use it.

Then you can have server startup code listen to that server and on connection of it perform the options for any event.

```
var listener = io.listen(server);
listener.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('locationClick', function(data) {
        // perform the function on receving locationClick event.
    }
}
```